# SeleniumExtras.PageObjects does not exist in Selenium extras

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, automated-tests, pageobjects

I created a new project in Visual Studio and I am trying to use PageObjects

I am using the following NuGet packages

```
DotNetSeleniumExtras.PageObjects 3.11.0
DotNetSeleniumExtras.PageObjects.Core 3.12.0
```

When I type `using SeleniumExtras.` all I see is `using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers`

I am trying to implement the following:

```
public abstract class BasePage

    {
        private static T GetPage<T>() where T : new()
        {
            var page = new T();
            PageFactory.InitElements(WebDriver.Driver, page);
            return page;
        }
```

Why isn't PageObjects showing up? has it been deprecated in these versions?

[image]

Comment: Which version of .NET is your project targeting? .NET Framework, .NET Core, .NET Standard?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this information. It is vital, and gets lost easily in comments.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I added that intial comment by mistake. I added screenshot of my properties. Would the fact its a class library make a difference?

Comment: Try closing Visual Studio, deleting the.vs folder inside your solution directory, and reopening the solution. This sounds *really* wonky.